# Constraint to fix sum of rows and colums of a multi dimensional matrix

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

Looking a generic solution for m x n matrix e.g. For a 2x4 array, I need to have the sum of even rows to be 60, and that of even columns to be 40.
With the following code, the row condition is working but the columns condition is not.  Please let me know how to solve it.

```
    class c1;
     rand bit[7:0] matrix[2][4];
     constraint c1 { foreach (matrix[i])
     if(i%2==0)
     matrix[i].sum with(int'(item))==60;
     }
     constraint c2 { foreach (matrix[j])
     if(j%2==0)
     matrix.sum with (int'(matrix[item.index][j]))==200;}
    endclass

    module m1;
     c1 obj;
     initial
     begin
      obj=new();
      obj.randomize();
      $display("matrix  is %p",obj);
     end
    endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to create a second matrix with the rows and columns rotated.

```
class c1#(parameter N=2,M=4);
  rand bit[7:0] matrix[N][M];
  rand bit[7:0] matrix_rot[M][N];
  constraint c_rot {
    foreach (matrix[i,j]) {
       matrix[i][j] == matrix_rot[j][i];
    }
  }
  constraint c_row {
    foreach (matrix[i]) {
      if (i%2==0) {
        matrix[i].sum with(int'(item)) == 60;
      }
    }
  }
  constraint c_col {
    foreach (matrix_rot[i]) {
      if (i%2==0) {
        matrix_rot[i].sum with(int'(item)) == 40;
      }
    }
  }
endclass
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: this answers the question as it was originally asked.

---

For such a small matrix, this is trivial:

```
   localparam COLSUM = 40;
   constraint c2 { 
        matrix[0][0] + matrix[1][0] == COLSUM;
        matrix[0][2] + matrix[1][2] == COLSUM;
   }
```

Obviously, this does not scale well if you need to create a bigger matrix, but it gets the job done for what you have.

Using the `sum` method works for your "row" because it corresponds to a single dimension of your 2D array.  However, it is not as simple for your "column" because that cuts across both dimensions.